# jQuery UI - tab hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I had this kind of code :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
          // Tabs
          $('#headlinks').tabs();
    });
</script>


<div id="headlinks">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#file1.htm"><span>MYUNIVERSITY</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#file2.htm"><span>MYCAMPUS TOOLS</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, how do i remove the '#' symbols in the hyperlinks? if i remove the '#' symbol, the tab will be displayed 'loading...' every time i clicked on it. Actualy I'm trying to make a hyperlink like [this website](http://k-commodities.kppk.gov.my/dashboard/dataset/1). As you can see, the website using jquery-ui tabs. I don't want the page loaded in a tab. I want those tab will be act like normal hyperlink

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**target="_blank"**

```
<li><a href="#file1.htm" target="_blank" ><span>MYUNIVERSITY</span></a></li>
```

You are also missing a:

```
</script>
```

**@YOUR EDITS:**

You are mixing two things then. If you no longer need the JQuery tabs, then take out that script at the top and build your own menu. Using the JQuery just to render out well aligned, nice looking tabs is like owning a car just to use the air conditioning.

**Solution:**

Take out Jquery script, build your own menu, get rid of # from href links, use target="_blank".

Comment: i'd edited my question and give some more explaination on what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery-UI `script` tag is not closed.
Close the script tag above, and as [Dan Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113921/dan-kanze) said, add a `target="_blank"` attribute to the anchor tags.

The tab functionality that you are looking for has a good explanation [**here**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).
JavaScript Code :

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of doing this

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var url = ui.tab;

        if( url ) {
            url.replace('#','');
            location.href = url;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```